# DateTime Regular expression

Tags: regex, validation, datetime

Need help with Regular expression for datetime (1949-01-01T00:00:00.000Z)

Comment: Have you tried anything? What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: You should try something first. https://regex101.com/r/Z6VZvG/1

Answer (score 0):

For exact match  (1949-01-01T00:00:00.000Z) you can use

> ((.*))

it will match enything inside parentheses